# Pandas: How to calculate the value of a column based on the value of the index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[Updated with reproducible example] I am trying to calculate the value of a dataframe column based on a conditional statement and values of the index and another column. The data is my household electricity consumption for every 30 minute period for the year 2023.

Here is sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# Generate Sample Input Data
start = dt.datetime.strptime("2023-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
hours = pd.date_range(start, start+pd.Timedelta("3 hours"), freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start': hours, 'kWh': [1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4]})
df.set_index('Start', inplace=True)

#example tariff
tariff = [
    { 'time': dt.datetime.strptime("01:00", "%H:%M").time(),
      'cost': 1.0 },
    { 'time': dt.datetime.strptime("02:00", "%H:%M").time(),
      'cost': 3.0 },
    { 'time': 'default',
      'cost': 2.0}
]

#helper function to calc cost based on time of day from index
def calc_cost(index, row):
    row_time = index.time()
    
    consumption = row['kWh']

    # there may be more elif clauses in the real world
    if row_time == tariff[0]['time']:
            return consumption * tariff[0]['cost']
    elif row_time == tariff[1]['time']: 
            return consumption * tariff[1]['cost']
    else:
            return consumption * tariff[2]['cost']

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, 'tariff'] = calc_cost( index, row )
```

This approach produces the output I expect and I can have more complex helper function if needed (e.g. my real code checks for time within ranges rather than just checking for equality).

Here is an alternate solution based on the solution proposed by @Corralian using my example data:

```
# fill with default value
df['tariff 2'] = tariff[2]['cost'] * df.loc[:,'kWh']

# override default with specific prices
df.loc[time == tariff[0]['time'], 'tariff 2'] = tariff[0]['cost'] * df.loc[:,'kWh']
df.loc[time == tariff[1]['time'], 'tariff 2'] = tariff[1]['cost'] * df.loc[:,'kWh']
```

What is the recommended approach of achieving this, I'm new to Pandas and have tried other approaches using .apply and .iterrows without success.

Thanks!

Comment: `apply` and `iterrows` should never be your first attempt, you most likely can vectorize your operations, please provide a [mre] with dummy data

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have few cases, the best idea is use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) indexer:

```
# Extract hour from datetime index
hours = df.index.hour

# Fill with the default electricity rate
df['Tariff 2'] = tariff_2_costs['price_per_kWh_default']

# Override with specific price
df.loc[(hours >= 2) & (hours < 5), 'Tariff 2'] = tariff_2_costs['price_per_kWh_0200-0500']
df.loc[(hours >= 16) & (hours < 19), 'Tariff 2'] = tariff_2_costs['price_per_kWh_1600-1900']
```

Output:

```
>>> df.head(20)
                           Tariff 2
2023-01-01 00:00:00+00:00     30.12
2023-01-01 00:30:00+00:00     30.12
2023-01-01 01:00:00+00:00     30.12
2023-01-01 01:30:00+00:00     30.12
2023-01-01 02:00:00+00:00     15.87
2023-01-01 02:30:00+00:00     15.87
2023-01-01 03:00:00+00:00     15.87
2023-01-01 03:30:00+00:00     15.87
2023-01-01 04:00:00+00:00     15.87
2023-01-01 04:30:00+00:00     15.87
2023-01-01 05:00:00+00:00     30.12
2023-01-01 05:30:00+00:00     30.12
2023-01-01 06:00:00+00:00     30.12
2023-01-01 06:30:00+00:00     30.12
2023-01-01 07:00:00+00:00     30.12
2023-01-01 07:30:00+00:00     30.12
2023-01-01 08:00:00+00:00     30.12
2023-01-01 08:30:00+00:00     30.12
2023-01-01 09:00:00+00:00     30.12
2023-01-01 09:30:00+00:00     30.12
```

There are other ways with `pd.cut` and `np.select` to do the same but it's not very useful in your case.

With [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
hours = df.index.hour

conds = [(hours >= 2) & (hours < 5),
         (hours >= 16) & (hours < 19)]

choices = [tariff_2_costs['price_per_kWh_0200-0500'],
           tariff_2_costs['price_per_kWh_1600-1900']]

default = tariff_2_costs['price_per_kWh_default']

df['Tariff 2'] = np.select(condlist=conds, choicelist=choices, default=default)
```

With [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
hours = [0, 2, 5, 16, 19, 24]
prices = [tariff_2_costs['price_per_kWh_default'],
          tariff_2_costs['price_per_kWh_0200-0500'],
          tariff_2_costs['price_per_kWh_default'],
          tariff_2_costs['price_per_kWh_1600-1900'],
          tariff_2_costs['price_per_kWh_default']]

df['Tariff 2'] = pd.cut(df.index.hour, bins=hours, labels=prices,
                        ordered=False, include_lowest=True, right=False)
```

Comment: @Hat. What's wrong with the current answer now you have changed your question?

Comment: Your answer was really helpful, thanks. Others asked for a sample data so I needed to rewrite and simplify - I've included your answer with credit and marked your response as helpful (although got a message that it won't show up until I have more 'reputation'.